Group.Users Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied
I'm receiving a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException ([System.UnauthorizedAccessException] -2147024891)
when I try to query the Users of a Group:
        var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _appID, _appSecret);
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        GroupCollection collGroup = site.SiteGroups;

        // Get the visitors group, assuming its ID is 4.
        Group visitorsGroup = collGroup.GetById(4);
        clientContext.Load(visitorsGroup);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // Get the users
        var collUsers = visitorGroup.Users;
        ctx.Load(collUser);
        ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry(10);

The same code works in an old application that we're migrating from OfficeDevPnP.Core to PnP.Framework.
The user that connects to Sharepoint Online is the same, an AAD application:
// NEW CODE WITH APP ID AND APP SECRET
var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _appID, _appSecret);            
// OLD CODE WITH APP ID AND CERTIFICATE
var clientContext = authManager.GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, _appID, tenantID, certPATH, certPass);

All other functions work perfectly, the only problem is the users in a group.
